# How to check if the authenticated user is a regular ASP.NET Identity account or an account linked to an external provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I need something like this:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var user = await AccountManager.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    if (user != null)
    {
        if (regular account)
        {
             // do this
        }

        if (external provider account)
        {
             // do that
        }
    }
}
```

I found this in the debugger but I don't know if that's the right one to use for checking?

```
user.Logins.FirstOrDefault().LoginProvider
```

Which returns "Google"

Comment: What is the value of "LoginProvider"? If it's a type name, then that's probably your answer.

Comment: LoginProvider is a String. Turns out I can't use LoginProvider. Gave me Object not set to an instance of an object during testing. So it's not reliable apparently. There must be some other, better and more safe way to check?

Answer (score 1):

For those looking, in ASP.NET Core 3.1 you can ask the user manager if the user has a password:

```
var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).ConfigureAwait(false);
var hasPassword = await UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

So all users can have passwords and external logins just to be clear.  After a new user comes back from google/facebook, they are prompted to create a local user (which associates a login).  If you want to test for the case where the user only has a password and no other logins, you can just see if the user has any associated logins.

```
UserManager.GetUserLogins().Count == 0
```

Keep in mind, users can unlink their accounts, and also link accounts via the manage page, so they will not necessarily stay in the same bucket over time...